# The correct term for when a corporation takes over or expands into a new industry?

Tags: word-choice

For example, if we wanted to express how Google is expanding rapidly into all areas of the internet and material world, how could we say it? The emphasis here in on their expansion into multiple industries and institutions.

Conglomerate? (as a verb)
Amalgamate?
Merge?
Fuse?
Synthesize?
Consolidate?

So many seem viable, but I know there has to be the one that suits the purpose the most effectively here.

Comment: [This guy](https://www.project-syndicate.org/commentary/consumer-sharing-economy-adaptation-by-mohamed-a--el-erian-2015-04?barrier=true) calls it _Creative Self-Disruption_... whilst [this madam](https://www.project-syndicate.org/commentary/blurred-industry-lines-by-lucy-p--marcus-2015-03) doesn't really know how to call it...

Comment: fyi, conglomerate is a type of business concern. It is not a verb. Diversify as given in the first answer is the only verb to use here.

Comment: VERB

[NO OBJECT]
Pronunciation: /kənˈɡlɒməreɪt/
1. Gather together into a compact mass:
‘atoms which conglomerate at the centre’

1.1 Form a conglomerate by merging diverse firms:
‘the urge to conglomerate has long been out of fashion in American boardrooms’

Comment: according to Oxford Dictionaries:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conglomerate

Comment: Can I verb octopus? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/octopus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Diversify* is the appropriate term. When moving into a roughly parallel industry (as Google often does), the term is [*horizontal diversification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversification_(marketing_strategy)):

> The company adds new products or services that are often technologically or commercially unrelated to current products but that may appeal to current customers. This strategy tends to increase the firm's dependence on certain market segments. For example, a company that was making notebooks earlier may also enter the pen market with its new product.

[Wikipedia: Diversification (marketing strategy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversification_(marketing_strategy))

Comment: Diversify is the only term for the OP's idea.

Comment: @Lambie You're right. I was hedging my bets. Naughty, naughty!

Comment: My comment was directed at everyone else. Not you. :)

Comment: @Mick You beat me by about a minute. I agree with Lambie.

Comment: Thanks Mick. Vincent Miller coins a similar term for this process, he expresses it as 'horizontal integration'

Comment: Excellent related source to back up your answer: https://cnnumerique.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/PlatformNeutrality_VA.pdf

(page 12, second paragraph) "Google is a thriving business with great capacity for innovation. ... 

         **It is now diversifying** into numerous economic sectors: digital technology (content, email, OSs, mobile terminals, communication networks), flow control (advertising, listing), business intermediation (travel, insurance, services), sector-based services (Google maps, urban living, automobile, home
automation), etc."

Answer (score 1):

I would make a case for "proliferate" as it carries the sense of multiplying, enlarging, growing, etc.